# LDAP search filter for searching multiple users groups in one query

Tags: ldap

I need to get all memberships of users from groupofuniquenames typed entry that has membership data in uniqueMember attribute. Groups look like this:

```
dn: cn=GROUP1,ou=groups,dc=zxc
objectclass: groupofuniquenames
uniqueMember: uid=1252611,ou=users,dc=zxc
uniqueMember: uid=23893,ou=users,dc=zxc
uniqueMember: uid=95044,ou=users,dc=zxc
uniqueMember: uid=127121,ou=users,dc=zxc

dn: cn=GROUP2,ou=groups,dc=zxc
objectclass: groupofuniquenames
uniqueMember: uid=1252611,ou=users,dc=zxc
uniqueMember: uid=589454,ou=users,dc=zxc
uniqueMember: uid=34848,ou=users,dc=zxc
uniqueMember: uid=1252612,ou=users,dc=zxc
```

However if i use filter like this

```
(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(|(uniqueMember=uid=1252611,ou=users,dc=zxc)(uniqueMember=uid=1252612,ou=users,dc=zxc)))
```

I get results like this

```
dn: cn=GROUP1,ou=groups,dc=zxc
objectclass: groupofuniquenames
uniqueMember: uid=1252611,ou=users,dc=zxc
cn: GROUP1

dn: cn=GROUP2,ou=groups,dc=zxc
objectclass: groupofuniquenames
uniqueMember: uid=1252611,ou=users,dc=zxc
cn: GROUP2
```

So the search results do not contain info that 1252612 is also member of GROUP2. They only return results for one match for the OR condition in LDAP search filter. So the problem is caused because users in the filter query can belong to same groups, but the group result is returned only for one user.

I also don't understand why the returned uniqueMember attribute doesn't contain data for all memberships, if this is possible to achieve it would also be helpful.

Comment: how are you making the query? the filter does not control which attributes are returned

Comment: the problem here really doesn't have anything to do with which attributes are returned...

Comment: from your question:
"I also don't understand why the returned uniqueMember attribute doesn't contain data for all memberships, if this is possible to achieve it would also be helpful."

It seems like the result is correct the sense that all expected groups are returned, but the attributes are incomplete. Am I missing something?

Comment: the actual problem here is that the search results do not contain the fact that uid 1252612 is also member of GROUP2

Comment: What language are you using? The uniqueMember attribute should be multivalued with all matching users (a different problem than the one you encounter -- you should see *all* of the members whether they were part of your filter or not). But if you're only accessing element 0 of the multi-value attribute ... you'd only see the first member from the list.

Comment: not any language, this is ldapsearch result